# GPU vs CPU, Circumstances and Graphic Processing

Tags: c#, cpu, gpu

My main question is this: for graphic processing (e.g. moving images, collisions, scaling etc.), is there something I can do to get the best performance out of the processing? Under what circumstances is the GPU used instead of the CPU, and can I selectively use one over the other? Should I? Also, what Graphic API should I use if I wanted to get the best performance with graphic processing. Or should I even use an API at all?

I feel as though I'm asking to many questions in one Question, or that I'm not wording it correctly, but I don't see how I could do otherwise. If any clarification is needed, just ask. I've searched many places, but this may be a duplicate, so my apologies if it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are creating, but these are my musings on the subject:

A good option is **XNA**. That is basically a wrapper on top of DirectX that is made for utilizing the GPU for graphic intensive tasks, but hides some of the dirty implementation of using DirectX directly. Your best option for games, graphical simulations etc.

Another option is **WPF** that also uses DirectX at the bottom, but is more geared towards creating user interfaces than games and similar tasks, but is extremely flexible.

**WinForms/GDI+** is your worst option, since it does not use hardware acceleration at all, and will only use the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll probably use XNA, but I was wondering if there was any way to use DirectX directly, or if the only option was a wrapper.

Comment: There's SlimDX too, which, like XNA, is a .NET wrapper around DirectX, but, from what I've seen, is much better designed (and exposes more of the DirectX API). The downside is that it doesn't support other platforms like XBox360 or Windows Phone.

Comment: @GunnarJ: DirectX is a C/C++ API, so it's not directly accessible from .NET. You could p/invoke all the necessary functions, or you can use an existing wrapper which does the same thing for you.

Comment: @GunnarJ - Managed DirectX is deprecated and XNA has taken over it's place. You can look into some other DirectX wrapper projects, for example SlimDX (http://slimdx.org/) or SharpDX (http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/)